# When is the intersection of the hyperboloid with the sphere transverse?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

> For which values of $a$ does the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ intersect
>   the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a$ transversally? What does the intersection
>   look like for different values of $a$?

What I can see is that if $\sqrt a<1, $ then the intersection is empty and hence transverse. If $\sqrt a=1\iff a=1$, then the intersection points lie on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ on the $z=0$ plane. I guess at those points the tangent spaces to the hyperboloid and the sphere coincide (they are 2-dim planes). Is that correct? How do I show it more rigorously? (I can use local parametrizations of those manifolds and then compute the image of the corresponding differentials, but this seems to be a huge hassle.) As for the case $\sqrt a > 1$, I guess here the intersection is transverse, but again, how do I show it?

Comment: Think about normal vectors! Tangent spaces coincide precisely when normal vectors are parallel.

Comment: But why is this helpful? I imagine normal vectors as vectors orthogonal to tangent spaces, so it seems to me that in formal proofs everything boils down to tangent spaces in any case. Besides, Guillemin and Pollack don't even define normal vectors (at least I don't remember them talking about normal vectors).

Comment: No, they talk about the dual notion: Namely, $\ker(df_x) = T_x M$ for $M=f^{-1}(c)$ a level set of $f$ (for a regular value $c$). So think about $df_x$ and $dg_x$ ...

Comment: @TedShifrin So in the case $a=1$, the differentials of $f$ and $g$ at $x$ (where $x$ is any intersection point) have the same kernels (since a point in the intersection is of the form $(x,y,0)$), and thus the intersection is not transverse. In the case $a > 1$, the kernels will be different, and each of them will be 2-dimensional, so the intersection will be transverse?

Comment: This is correct. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Why the kernels will will be different? why each of them will be 2-dimensional? @user500094

Comment: To cover the remaining case, you might want to add that for $a < 0$ (where $\sqrt{a}$ isn't even defined), the intersection remains empty, hence transverse (said the Keeper of the Empty Set).

Comment: You might also (although you'll want to use normal vectors for this) ask for which values of $a$ (if any) is the intersection not merely transverse, but orthogonal.

Comment: what is the relation between transversality and orthogonality?

Comment: what is the relation between transversality and orthogonality? @JohnHughes what if we had this hyperboloid instead $x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = 1$

Comment: Well...if the planes intersect orthogonally (i.e., their normal vectors are perpendicular), then they're certainly transverse (although not vice-versa!). As for that other hyperboloid: testing for orthogonality in that case looks very much the same as in the case presented in the problem.

Comment: is not normal means perpendicular? @JohnHughes

Comment: The normal vector to a plane is a (typically unit-length) vector that is perpendicular to the plane itself. Two planes are said to be perpendicular if their normal vectors are perpendicular.

Answer (score 3):

For $a=1$ we obtain $$x^2+y^2=1\\z=0$$therefore the intersection is the unit circle on XY plane centered at (0,0). Generally for $a>1$ we have $$z^2+1=a-z^2$$ therefore$$z=\pm \sqrt {a-1\over 2}\\ x^2+y^2={a+1\over 2}$$

Also for a 2 sheet hyperboloid for example for $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$ we must have $$z^2-1=a-z^2$$ or $z^2={a+1\over 2}$ in which $a\ge -1$. If so, we have $$x^2+y^2=z^2-1={a-1\over 2}$$which is possible only if $a\ge 1$. 
 **Conclusion: the intersection of the two planes contains two unit circles parallel to XY plane centered at $(0,0,\pm\sqrt{a-1\over 2})$ in the former case and $(0,0,\pm\sqrt{a+1\over 2})$ in the latter case**

Here is an image (simulated by MATLAB) indicating the two sheet hyperboloid case:

[image]

Comment: what about the use of the Kernel mentioned in the above comments?

Comment: Actually i don't know what Kernel is. Can you elaborate on it a little?

Comment: why it is not transversal if $a=1$ as mentioned in the above comments?

Comment: what if it is a 2 sheet hyperboloid?

Comment: I added some more details. Soon I will add some images..

Comment: $Ker f = \{ x \in D_{f} | f(x) = 0 \}$ ..... this is the meaning of the kernel

Comment: Then you may use the kernel as following: $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2-1$ and $g_a(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-a$ and $Ker(f-g_a)=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3| (f-g_a)(x,y,z)=0\}$ which is the answer